# Grammatical clarification on ''recognises needs to be crushed'

Tags: grammar

I'm a bit confused on how the grammar works here in terms of 'recognize', it should be "recognise something", right? What's the role here for 'needs', it's a noun or verb?

Should the sentence be "recognise the arrogance *which* needs to be crushed" *or*
"recognise the arrogance *as* needs to be crushed"?

> His arrogance, as reflected in his contemptuous statement, “Who is the Lord?” is what God recognizes needs to be crushed.

Comment: You've mis-parsed the text. It's ***His arrogance** [as reflected in his contemptuous statement, “Who is the Lord?”] **is what God recognizes needs to be crushed.*** Same as ***Your parsing is what** [I think] **needs to change***.

Comment: **1** His arrogance, as reflected in his contemptuous statement, “Who is the Lord?” is what God recognizes needs to be crushed. = **2** **Simplified**: God recognizes that what needs to be crushed is his arrogance, as reflected in his contemptuous statement, “Who is the Lord?” = **3** God recognizes *the thing that* needs to be crushed is his arrogance, *which was demonstrated by his contemptuous statement*, “Who is the Lord?”

Comment: Note that there's nothing ungrammatical with the sentence as it's written. So, it doesn't *need* to be written differently. However, for clarity, it *can* be written differently. But there's no obvious way of rephrasing it that's any better than any number of other ways. So, with respect to how it *should* be written, any answer is going to be subjective.

Answer (score 3):

The sense is *his arrogance...is what, [as] God recognises, needs to be crushed.*

I don't think it's particularly well expressed. I would prefer *is what God recognises as needing to be crushed.*